# Is there an app that could create a daily checklist from a template?

Tags: macos, ios, applications, productivity

I'm looking for an app that could automate some of my routines at work.

Each working day I start with checking emails, new issues in bugtrack, cup of coffee and etc.

Some of the work requires step by step following a checklist (new release for example).

Each time I need to create a new document, paste there a template of the checklist and follow it.

I wonder, is there an app that could add some automation in that process? Like create a daily checklist automatically or handle a history of each day.

Thanks.

Comment: My office tracks projects on Asana. I have private, recurring daily and weekly tasks I just use myself. Many include sub-task workflows. I can't quite recommend Asana personally since the non-free packages are pricey, but _would_ I suggest you look at some project- or time- management solutions since, while not built to your exact purpose, they may suit your need as a side-feature. E.g. Asana, Trello, BaseCamp, [look around?](https://www.softwareadvice.com/project-management/)

Comment: @JoelReid Thank you, trello actually looks very good since it allows to automate tasks of copying new boards. Thanks, If you convert your comment to answer I'll mark it as current.